# Image filtering - wrong results?

Tags: image-processing, scipy, filtering, convolution

I'm experimenting with convolving an image with a user-supplied mask, in this case

```
u = array([[-2,-2,-2],[-2,25,-2],[-2,-2,-2]])/9
```

using the commands

```
In[1]:  import scipy.ndimage as ndi
In[2]:  import skimage.io as io 
In[3]:  c = io.imread('cameraman.png')
In[4]:  cu = ndi.convolve(c,u)
In[5]:  io.imshow(cu)
```

I'm checking this against commands in GNU Octave:

```
Octave-3.8: 1> c = imread('cameraman.png');
Octave-3.8: 2> u = [-2 -2 -2;-2 25 -2;-2 -2 -2]/9
Octave-3.8: 3> cu = imfilter(c,u)
Octave-3.8: 4> imshow(cu)
```

But here's the thing: Octave seems to give the correct result, but Python doesn't, even though the commands `convolve` and `imfilter` are supposed to be implementing the same algorithm.  (Well in fact `imfilter` performs a correlation, which in this case is the same as a convolution.)

The Octave output is:

[image]!

and the Python output is:

[image]!

which as you can see is very different to the Octave result.  Does anybody know what's going on here?  Or is there a better way of convolving with a user-supplied linear filter than using `convolve`?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?  In Python 2, `u = array([[-2,-2,-2],[-2,25,-2],[-2,-2,-2]])/9` uses integer division.  Change `9` to `9.0`, or add `from __future__ import division` at the top of your file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! - but actually I was in fact using the array defined in such a way that it had a floating point type - I just described it that way above for ease of explanation.  And even putting a 9.0 as you recommend doesn't change the output.  (I'm using Python 2.7).

Comment: Trying converting the image to floating point before calling `ndi.convolve`; e.g. `cu = ndi.convolve(c.astype(float),u)`.  I get something different, but it doesn't look the same as your octave output.

Comment: One thing that seems to work: convolve with the image of type float (as you say), but then display the result with `imshow(cu/255,cmap=cm.gray,vmax=1.0,vmin-0.0)` Setting `vmax` and `vmin` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the result of your convolution taking your image luminance values out of bounds.  I ran the example below in Matlab (~=Octave) and for an image that initially has grey values 0-255 so in normalised range [0,0.99] the result ends in with pixels in range [-0.88,2.03].

```
>> img=double(imread('cameraman.tif'))./255;
>> K=[-2 -2 -2 ; -2 25 -2; -2 -2 -2]/9;
>> out=conv2(img,K,'same');
>> max(max(out))

ans =

    2.0288

>> min(min(out))

ans =

   -0.8776
```

It could be that Python has a problem visualising images with out of range grey values <0 or >255  and this is causing a clamping of values resulting in black/white halos in those areas. Perhaps Octave normalises the image prior to displaying it resulting in few artifacts.  If you normalise you image in Python prior to displaying it, do you still have this problem?

Comment: Yes, I thought of that too.  I've tried convolving with the image converted to float32 first, in which case the max and min are 517.3333 and -223.7778 respectively (which are simply your values multiplied by 255).  Transforming to uint8 for display with `cu2 = uint8(255*(cu - cu.min())/(cu.max()-cu.min()))` results in a very washed out image with low brightness range.  I've just upgraded my libraries numpy, scipy, scikit-image to their newest versions, and the issue still persists.